# Should all eligible users (in terms of reputation) be allowed to vote under the Triage queue?

Tags: discussion, triage

Currently, all the users with a certain reputation are allowed to vote on new questions under the *Triage* queue.

This, somehow, doesn't feel right to me, at least.

People give their opinion an a question belonging to a topic they have no clue about! This doesn't make sense.

Instead, I would love if only those questions are presented to me which belong to a topic I am already related to. This can be checked, for instance, by allowing only those questions which have a tag which already belongs to my profile. This way, I end up making a better decision over that question.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no different than all the other queues, where reviewers may face questions or answers about topics they don't know. Often you don't need to know the subject in depth to evaluate the post; otherwise you're trusted to use the "Skip" button to pass. So far it doesn't seem to have been a disaster.

Comment: Yeah, same applies to other queues as well!

Comment: I forgot about the presence of 'Skip' when asking this question. Thanks for reminding. :)

Comment: +1 to reemphasize how often it is that essentially no subject knowledge is required to review accurately. (In point of fact, I'd expect that the 500-rep population from, say, Cooking, would be able to correctly review at least 25% of Triage and correctly skip another 50-60%.)